# Freeradisu allow requests based on NAS-IDENTIFIER

Tags: freeradius

I am running FreeRADIUS Version 2.2.8. All of my NAS clients are on dynamic IP addresses from different ISP's, Therefore I would like to to Allow requests based on NAS-identifier rather then NAS IP?

Appreciate if someone can post hints or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with FreeRADIUS v3.0.x, as all clients are indexed on either IPv4 or IPv6 address, and FreeRADIUS does not decode packets until it has found a valid client.

FreeRADIUS v4.0.x will likely support this, but the work hasn't been completed yes as far as I'm aware.

Your main options are:

- Define a client for 0.0.0.0/0 and used the same shared secret everywhere.
- Colocate a RADSEC (RADIUS over TLS) Proxy on the same box as the access points, or in the same network, and use that to wrap the UDP RADIUS packets.
- Buy NAS with RADSEC support built in.

Comment: for the time being, using 0.0.0.0/0 approach I managed to solve it. using following code in authorize section
if ("%{sql: select nas_id from users where username = '%{User-Name}'}" != "%{NAS-Identifier}") {
update reply {
Reply-Message = 'Error: You are not allowed to connect form this NAS ! Bingo - zaib'
}
update control {
Auth-Type := "Reject"
}
}

Comment: each dealer have nas idetifier defined in there tablem tehrefore when php insert the new user, it automatically addsd the dealer nas-identifer , and using the sql if code, it query the nas_id and matches with the auth request nas-identifier !

Comment: Yep that'd work.  The only issue you can be DDOSed by anyone on the internet, but in reality, it's probably not a big deal.

I'd make the additional suggestion of using the do_not_respond unlang policy, so that you don't respond to NAS that you don't know, so the wider internet doesn't discover you have a RADIUS service running.

Comment: can you please share some steps on how can I prevent DDOS using do_not_respond unlag query?

Comment: Oh, just if the NAS-Identifier wasn't found, call out to the ``do_not_respond`` policy.  Then the server doesn't waste resources encoding the response, and unauthorized actors on the internet don't get a positive response indicating that there's a RADIUS server running.

Comment: Feel free to ask another question if you want the unlang code.  It's hard to put formatted text in comments.